# PySimpleGUI: Is it possible add elements like button inside the Tree?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm wondering whether it is possible to add element like button inside Tree? The example in the picture.
[Example of Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEpEq.png)

I tried to find an answer about this one but I didn't find clear answer for it.

Comment: IMO, the answer is No.

Comment: How should I design this layout?

Comment: What the layout mean ?